# How do I remove one's self from a community?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, communities-list

**NOTICE**: This is NOT a duplicate!! The title is REMOVE not DELETE. The UNJOIN feature is what I was after. Please read the full post. I hope this clarifies the difference.

How do I remove myself from a community? I don't recall how I joined one perhaps an accidental mouse click. But I would like to know how to 'unjoin' a Stack Exchange community.

To clarify, this is NOT an account delete request, only to 'UNJOIN' a community or two.

**UPDATE**: There needs to be clarification about the DELETE and UNJOIN. I found the DELETE postings and wanted to be clear in this post that I DO NOT want to DELETE, only UNJOIN.

Go ahead and delete this message as I did not intend to duplicate the other questions that ambiguously mix DELETE with UNJOIN.

Comment: No such thing as "unjoin".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to "unjoin" a community is to delete your account *on that site*.

You can do this yourself if you haven't participated (voted etc.). You'll find the "delete" link on your profile on the site(s) you want to remove:

[image]

If you have participated you'll need to contact the team using the contact us form at the bottom of every page and select the "I need to delete my user profile" option:

[image]

This will trigger the deletion of that profile. It's on a schedule so you can cancel it if you change your mind.

Comment: The popup could be a bit more talkative like "delete your profile on this site?".

Comment: From what I'm reading here it is not intuitive how to unjoin a community and perhaps would make for a feature request if you could tag comments but I don't see how to do that.  Also, I remember reading questions about the search area at the top right of the stack exchange site and remember other people were dissatisfied with it.  To find this answer I had to use google because the search didn't find it.